# How to show $\int_{\sum_{i = 1}^n \gamma_i} f = \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{\gamma_i} f$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Let $G \subset \mathbb C$ be an open set, $f: G \to \mathbb C$ a continuous function and $\gamma: [\alpha, \beta] \to G$ a contour. Define the contour integral of $f$ along $\gamma$ to be
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_\gamma f = \sum_{k = 1}^n \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)dt,
> \end{align*}
>   where $\alpha = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n = \beta$ is the partition of $[\alpha, \beta]$, associated to $\gamma = \sum_{i = 1}^n \gamma_i$.

I tried to prove the (simple) fact that, if we have a smooth contour then

> \begin{align*}
> \int_{\sum_{i = 1}^n \gamma_i} f = \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{\gamma_i} f.
> \end{align*}

I suppose it is straight forward, just with the definition, and I reached the following point:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\sum_{i = 1}^n \gamma_i} f &= \int_\alpha^\beta f\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \gamma_i(t)\right) \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \gamma_i(t)\right)' dt
= \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_\alpha^\beta f\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \gamma_i(t)\right) \gamma_i'(t) dt.
\end{align*}
The problem is, that I need $f(\gamma_i)$ instead of $f\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \gamma_i(t)\right)$ on the right hand side. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The sum of paths is the concatenation of paths. $$\int_{\sum \gamma_i} f(z) \,dz = \sum \int_{\gamma_i} f(z)\,dz$$ is the _definition_ of the integral over the sum of paths.

Comment: Ah yes of course, thanks for the explanation, I missunderstood the definition there.